# How to integrate $\int 1/(\sqrt {1+1/4v^2}) dv$?

Tags: calculus

How does one integrate $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt {1+\frac{1}{4v^2}}} dv$$?

I just couldn't get it - I know that inverse trignometric function will not fit into this form. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: [Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=examples/Calculus1SingleStepping) can be used to this end, especially the [IntTutor](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Student/Calculus1/IntTutor) command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: We can rearrange the integral as

$$\int \frac{2v}{\sqrt{4v^2 + 1}} dv$$

This suggests a substitution of $u = 4v^2 + 1$.